# Can not load JDBC driver. in

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

Test Plan.

1. Add one Thread Group with default settings.
2. Add JDBC Connection Configuration with below setting.

   [image]
3. Add JDBC Requset for Simple select stement.
4. Add Constant Timer with 5000 miliseconds Thread Delay.
5. Add View Results Tree.

My DBServer Name : proddbtest1.xyz.com
SQL Instance Name: Prodbtest1\LIVE

I fill up this parameter value in DB URL and Driver class. In fact I download latest JDBC sqljdbc42.jar from Net and past at Lib folder.
After running my test plan still I get an error message

> "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class
> com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"

Can any one help me where I am passing wrong configuration settings.

Comment: Sounds like the JAR with the missing class is not in your run time CLASSPATH.

Comment: You are using the configuration for the ancient SQL Server 2000 JDBC driver with the newest JDBC driver, somewhere around 2005 Microsoft changed the driver class name and the URL format.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Using the JDBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver) article the **correct** Microsoft JDBC Driver class name is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

you are trying to use the following one:

```
com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So replace `jdbc` and `sqlserver` and your setup will work.

Also don't forget to restart JMeter to pick the `sqljdbc42.jar` up.

Just in case see [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article to learn more about database load testing using JMeter

Comment: Also note that the JDBC URL should start with `jdbc:sqlserver:`, and not `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver:`.